# Swift: When adding a new file the device is iPhone but I can not change it

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have no idea why it is doing this and I am not fully aware of the repercussions. But whenever I add a new file to my project, I enter the name and so on but under the drop down for device, the texted is grayed out and iPhone is selected. I want to make my app universal but I can not seem to change this.

Any help is appreciated, and any insight on the problems I may now face from building an app with iPhone only files.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue when my schemes got fouled up after installing Xcode 7 Beta 5. I ran Xcode 6.4 and 7 beta 5 simultaneously at one point and something got mucked up. Shutting both down and rebooting coupled with running only one version at a time resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean universal between iPhone and iPad, then it's nothing to worry about. Your Swift files will compile to run on both iPhone and iPad without a problem! This is as long as you have set your `Deployment Info` properly in the Project Target.